# Stopping ViewPager AutoScroll onPause of the Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, adapter

I have an activity where I have a recyclerView. In that recyclerView, I am loading a list of cards. Each card is a viewPager with different images. I am autoScrolling the images also.

Now, I want to stop the autoScroll onPause of that activity.

```
private void loadViewPagerAdapter(final AutoScrollViewPager viewPager, final ArrayList<String> imageData, final int pos) {
        ImageCarousalAdapter imageCarousalAdapter = new ImageCarousalAdapter(context, imageData);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(imageData.size());
        viewPager.setAdapter(imageCarousalAdapter);
        viewPager.setInterval(6000);
        viewPager.setScrollDurationFactor(/*randomInRange(5.0f, 10.0f)*/20.0f);
        viewPager.setBorderAnimation(false);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutTranformer());
        viewPager.startAutoScroll();
    }
```

The above code is the method with which I am loading the recyclerView , viewPager Items.

Comment: please look at this link might help you https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager

Answer (score 0):

You should add an interface to the viewPager, and onPause of that activity, trigger that interface. I think this should work. Try it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

So solution for this is very simple,

Guessing that you are using [this library](https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager).

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(viewPager!=null)
        viewPager.stopAutoScroll();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(viewPager!=null)
        viewPager.startAutoScroll();
}
```

Note : The stopAutoScroll method at the onPause() method.

Hope this works for you!!

Comment: Yes, I am using that library. But in my Activity, I don't have the ViewPager. The viewPager is present in RecyclerView's Adapter.

Comment: So your answer was not helpful.